# How can i get delphi to create/open the form just like the first time

Tags: delphi

I have this code:

the first time i open it does exactly what i need it to do... a student answers the questions and depending on how many right/wrong, it displays a smiley face.... the first time i open the form it works and it does that, but the second time everything runs fine but the smiley face is not displayed

```
procedure TFUNIDAD1_ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.Ipregunta1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Integer;
begin
  for x := 1 to 6 do
    if Sender = Preguntas[x] then // Valida el panel que generó el evento
    begin
      // para Moverlo
      Respuestas[vCodigo].Top := Preguntas[x].Top; // Mueve el boton ubicado en la posicion capturada
                                      //en la variable codigo
      Respuestas[vCodigo].Left := Preguntas[x].Left;/////////
      //para validar

      if x = vCodigo then // Valida si la posicion del panel que genero el evento
      begin       //es igual a la que esta almacenada en Codigo
        Imagenes[x].Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\Educso\Imagenes\Actividades\accept.bmp');
        // si son iguales pone Correcto
        vBuenas := vBuenas + 1;
      end
      else
      begin
        Imagenes[x].Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\Educso\Imagenes\Actividades\delete.bmp');
        // De lo Contrario pone Incorrecto
        vMalas := vMalas + 1;
      end;
    end;

  if vMalas + vBuenas = 6 then
  begin
    if vBuenas = 6 then
      icarita1.Visible := True
    // ICarita.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\Educso\Imagenes\Actividades\Muy Bien.png')
    else
    if (vbuenas < 6) and (vBuenas <> 0)  then
      icarita2.Visible := True
    // ICarita.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\Educso\Imagenes\Actividades\Bien.png')
    else
    if vBuenas = 0 then
      icarita3.Visible := True;
    // ICarita.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\Educso\Imagenes\Actividades\Malo-1.png');
  end;
end;
```

Could it be because of the way i am calling the form?

```
if assigned (ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA) 
ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.free; 
ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.close; 
ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA:=TFUNIDAD1_ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.CREATE(APPLICATION);
ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.show;
```

vMalas and vBuenas count how many right/wrong questions are there.

```
var FUNIDAD1_ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA: TFUNIDAD1_ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA; 
Respuestas:Array [1..6] of TIMAGE;
//Respuestas Preguntas:Array[1..6] of TIMAGE; 
//Preguntas Imagenes:Array[1..6] of TIMAGE; 
//Cotejos vCodigo:integer;
vBuenas:Integer=0; 
vMalas:Integer=0;
```

Comment: could it be because of the way i am calling the form?             if assigned (ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA)                                ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.free;
ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.close;
ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA:=TFUNIDAD1_ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.CREATE( APPLICATION)
ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA.show;

Comment: are vMalas and vBuenas global variables which are not reset?

Comment: I think that @bummi hit the problem, but to your first comment; that call of `if Assigned(Form) then Form.Free;` is useless; it's enough to call `Form.Free;`, or better `Form.Release`. What is wrong (but not the reason of your problem) is calling `Close` on a released object later on. In all cases, we need more code from you to understand the logic behind those `vMalas` and `vBuenas` variables.

Comment: That's just to count how many right/wrong questions are there and then display a yellow/red/green smiley face.

Comment: var
  FUNIDAD1_ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA: TFUNIDAD1_ACTIVIDAD_COMPLETA;
      Respuestas:Array [1..6] of TIMAGE;//Respuestas
      Preguntas:Array[1..6] of TIMAGE; //Preguntas
      Imagenes:Array[1..6] of TIMAGE; //Cotejos
      vCodigo:integer;
      vBuenas:Integer=0;
      vMalas:Integer=0;
     Global variables

Comment: So it seems that you really need to reset the `vMalas` and `vBuenas` values to 0 if they are declared as global variables. Are you doing that somewhere in your code ? Global variables are not being reset if you free the form; their values remain. It's enough to click the `Ipregunta` button 2 times and their sum will be 12, not 6 as you expect (`if vMalas + vBuenas = 6 then`), which leads to the problem that none of the smiley images is shown.

Comment: when y try form.release/nil i always get an error.

Comment: @infospy I have moved the additional info from your comments into the question, but those code parts are still a mess. Please clean up your question, and next time do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks TLama and the rest, it was just resetting the variable. THanks Jan Doggen, i am new and learning, i'll do better next time.